# $\pm$ notation ambiguity

Tags: soft-question, notation

Imagine I want to present the list
$$
\{(0,2),(0,-2),(-1,1),(1,-1),(1,2),(-1,-2) \}
$$
in a shorter manner, by using "$\pm$". What is the best way to do that?

Initially, I thought that using, for example,
$$
\{ (0,\pm2),(\pm1,\mp1),(\pm1,\pm2) \}
$$
would be enough, where using "$\mp$" would give away the fact that $(\pm1,\mp 1)$ represents only two pairs and therefore $(\pm1,\pm2)$ represents also two pairs. However, another interpretation might suggest that $(\pm1,\pm2)$ represents four pairs, all the possible combinations $\{(1,2),(-1,2),(1,-2),(-1,-2)\}$. So this notation generates ambiguity.

I think this can be solved by instead writing
$$
\{ \pm(0,2),\pm(1,-1),\pm (1,2) \}
$$
or even
$$
\pm\{ (0,2),(1,-1),(1,2) \}
$$
I wonder, however, if there is a general approach to this kind of notations. What is the best way of using the "$\pm$" notation and why?

Comment: The version $\pm \{...\}$ yields two set, not their union. I would prefer as few $\pm$ signs as possible. But the ambiguity remains.

Comment: You should state in text how many combinations there are, like "a set with 6 pairs".

Comment: I think your $\{\pm(0,2),\ldots$ solution is clearly best.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$(\pm1,\pm2)$$ is indeed ambiguous, as you don't know if the two signs are synchronous or not and the expression can be read as two or four pairs.

On the opposite,

$$(\pm1,\mp2)$$ would certainly be understood as two pairs, otherwise the $\mp$ would be illogical.

So

$$\pm(1,2)$$ and $$\pm(1,-1)$$ are better, and as you are describing a set all combinations are allowed.

Anyway, had you been describing, say, a sum, then the expression would still have been ambiguous, by not knowing if the three $\pm$ are synchronized (six or eight terms ?).

A notation with the operator before the braces, meaning an implied distribution over the elements, is quite unusual.

Answer (score 1):

I think the following is an unambiguous way of designating your set:
$$
\big\{ (0, \pm 2), \pm (1, -1), \pm (1, 2) \big\}.
$$